# d3dcompiler.dll missing error with Need for Speed: Most Wanted 2012 on Windows 8

Tags: technical-issues, windows-8, need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012

I installed Need for Speed: Most Wanted on my laptop but when I launch it it gives me a d3dcompiler.dll is missing error.

How can I fix this? The game has been reinstalled but still gives me the error!

Answer (score 2):

Try downloading this version of DirectX from Microsoft and running it:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35

Even though it only says it updates DX9, it also updates components in DX10 and DX11.  Running this fixed a very similar error message that I was getting.

Comment: There's an offline standalone installer here: http://www.filehippo.com/download_directx/

Comment: DirectX Offline installer dated June 2010 from Microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8109

Answer (score 0):

Try and install to a different location.

Answer (score -1):

you will need a file d3dcompiler.dll which will be available at dllfiles.com .but you will need to uninstall the game and paste tis file in System32 folder in c drive and reinstall it again

Comment: Why would a reinstall be necessary?

Comment: Downloading individual DLL files from 3rd party sites is not guaranteed to work and is risky.